# Discrete Probability: Uniformly random permutations of sets and Independent/Dependent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, permutations, random-variables

> **Question:**
>
> **a)** Let $n$ $\ge$ $3$ be an integer. Consider a uniformly random permutation $a_1$,$a_2$...$a_n$ of the set ${(1,2,...,n})$. Define the events:
>
> A = "$a_n$ = n"
>
> B = "$a_2$ $\gt$ $a_1$"
>
> Are these independent or dependent? Show why?

**Attempt:**

I have to show $P$($A$$\cap$$B$) = $P(A)P(B)$ to prove independence

If I take $n=3$: I get the set $({1,2,3})$ that can be arranged in $3$ ways that satisfy the

condition of "$a_2$ $\gt$ $a_1$". This is out of the total $8$ choices.

So, $Pr(B)$ $=$ $\frac{3}{8}$

For $Pr(A)$, I don't know what they mean by this. "$a_n$ = n". Isn't $a_n$ always going to be $n$? So, $Pr(A)$ = 1?

For $P$($A$$\cap$$B$) = $\frac{3}{8}$ $.$ 1 = $\frac{3}{8}$

$P$($A$$\cap$$B$) = $P(A)P(B)$ = $\frac{3}{8}$ = Independent!

> **Question:**
>
> **b)** Let $n$ $\ge$ $5$ be an integer. Consider a uniformly random permutation $a_1$,$a_2$...$a_n$ of the set ${(1,2,...,n})$. Define the events:
>
> A = "$a_1$ = 1"
>
> B = "$a_n$ $=$ $5$"
>
> What is $Pr$($A$$\cup$$B$)?
>
> a) $\frac{1}{n}$ $-$ $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$
>
> b) $\frac{2}{n}$ $-$ $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$ **(Answer)**
>
> c) $\frac{2}{n}$ $-$ $\frac{1}{n^2}$

**Attempt:**

For $n=5$, I can find the $P(A)$, $P(B)$ to be $\frac{1}{5}$

I have to show $P$($A$$\cup$$B$) = $P(A) $ + $ P(B)$ $-$ $P$($A$$\cap$$B$).

I am struggling to determine $P$($A$$\cap$$B$) for this. Would it just be $\frac{1}{5}$ $.$ $\frac{1}{5}$? That doesn't give me the correct solution for $n=5$ which should be 0.35.

Comment: I think you haven't understood what a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) is, and hence you're doing things very incorrectly. Please go and revise this. 

(Loosely, the set of permutations of a set $S$ is the set of all the different orderings you can write these numbers in. In the question, they give you the set in a uniformly random order - i.e., the numbers $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ are $(1,\dots,n)$ all jumbled up. Note that the size of sample space is $n!$, which for $n =3$ is $6$, not $8$. Also, $P(a_i = j) = 1/n$ for any $i,j,n$, & in particular $P(a_n = n) \neq 1$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a)

If you have $3$ numbers and you permute them, you have only $3!=6$ possibilities.

$$Pr(B)=\frac{1}{2}$$ from symmetry.

$$Pr(A)=\frac1{n!}$$

since there is only one sequence that satisfies that condition.

Also $$Pr(A \cap B)=Pr(A) \ne Pr(A)Pr(B)$$

hence they are not independent.

(b)

$$Pr(A)=Pr(B)=\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}=\frac1n$$

$$Pr(A\cap B)= \frac{(n-2)!}{n!}=\frac1{n(n-1)}$$

The idea is while two positions are fixed, we are free to permute the rest.

Try to avoid the temptation of thinking that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ unless you can justify that they are independent.